# Numeric column in cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

I'm new to cytoscape.
I want to make the width of edges in my network according to a certain number.

my file looks like this:

node1 node2 34.04
node3 node2 56.89
node4 node5 8.09
node1 node4 10.54

when I import my network file I choose column 3 to be the "interactions". Then the number in column 3 ends up in a string column, and can't be used to make a continuous mapping. When I import the same table as node attributes I am still only able to get it in to a string column.

I have tried to look in the manual and googled a lot - but I seem to be the only one having this problem. How do I solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Cytoscape 2.8.3. It probably applies for 3.?.?.

Like you say, with your file format, the numbers will be used to population "interaction", and that is a String attribute.

So, for your file, do not set the Interaction Type (red) in the Import Network from Table dialog. Instead, set Source Interaction (purple) to Column 1 and Target Interaction (orange) to Column 2. Then, in the table at the bottom of the dialog, click the column header Column 3. It will turn blue. It will then be imported as a floating point attribute as "Column 3", and you can use it in a Continuous mapper.